# Manually insert function to Javascript/Nodejs event queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, if I want to do this

```
function doA(callback) {
  console.log("Do A")
  callback()
}

function doB() {
  console.log("Do B")
}

function doC() {
  console.log("Do C")
}

doA(doC)
doB()
```

I want the output of

```
Do A
Do B
Do C
```

However, the only way to get this result would to use this hack to push item to the queue:

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    doTask();
  }, 0);
```

Is there a way to manually add an item to the javscript/nodejs event queue? I'm asking this more for theoretical exercise rather than any practical programming needs. It seems like there is no way to do any async task without first invoking built-in functions that is already async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` works fine, I don't consider it a hack. But there's also [`queueMicrotask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask), which might sound more suited to your purpose - it queues a microtask which'll run as soon as all other synchronous Javascript has finished executing:

```js
function doA(callback) {
  console.log("Do A")
  queueMicrotask(callback);
}

function doB() {
  console.log("Do B")
}

function doC() {
  console.log("Do C")
}

doA(doC)
doB()
```

It's basically equivalent to `Promise.resolve().then(callback)`.

Note that an immediate `setTimeout` queues a *macrotask* (one which will run once the event loop gets around to [processing the next message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), which may take a few milliseconds) - in contrast, `queueMicrotask` and `Promise.resolve.then` queues a microtask, which will run basically *immediately* after other synchronous JS is finished.

Also keep in mind that `queueMicrotask`, while supported in Node, is not exactly widely supported in browsers yet, so if you want to use it on a public-facing website, make sure to include a polyfill (or use the `Promise.resolve` method).